# Proving formula for the expected value of a discret function

Tags: probability, expected-value

I want to prove the formula for the [expected value of a discrete function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84l6T.jpg).
The proof in my book goes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebn0N.jpg)
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_k \left[ \sum_{g(j)=k} g(j) p_X (j) \right] &= \sum_k k \left[ \sum_{g(j)=k}p_X (j) \right] \\
& = \sum_k k \left[ \sum_{g(j)=k}P(X=j) \right] \\
& = \sum_k k P(g(X)=k) \\
& = \sum_k k p_Y(k) \\
& = \mathbb(E(Y))
\end{split}
$$
. I don't understand why the first step of the second image is equal to E(y) in the theorem in the first image. Also why is [this equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arrbn.jpg) and
$$
\sum_k k \left[ \sum_{g(j)=k}P(X=j) \right] = \sum_k k P(g(X)=k)
$$
?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still a bit confused about this